# (PostgreSQL) How to create a function based on a text argument and return a list

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `SELECT` statement that returns a list:

```
SELECT  "db"."accounts"."account" as account
FROM db.accounts
WHERE db.accounts.level = 'Level 4' AND db.accounts.report = 'Report A'
```

As report can be either Report A or Report B, I want to create a function that the user chooses which report, something like: get_account('Report A').

What I've tried:

```
CREATE TYPE get_accounts_results AS ARRAY[];

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_accounts(report TEXT) RETURNS get_accounts_results AS

    $$ 
        SELECT  "db"."accounts"."account" as account
        FROM db.accounts
        WHERE db.accounts.level = 'Level 4' AND db.accounts.report = $1
    $$

    LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT get_accounts('Report A') AS report_account;
```

This gives me back 1 value only, when in fact I need `n` values - the quantity of values on this list is dynamic. Probably the type being created is wrong, but I didn't find anything that made sense in this scenario.

My question is: how to adjust this query in order to get the result of the created function on a list?

*(PS: My end objective is to be able to iterate through this list to make a query that dynamically adds the query result to a materialized view)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your function to return a table. And you don't really need the type definition either:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_accounts(p_report TEXT) 
  RETURNS table(report_account text)
AS
$$ 
  SELECT act.account
  FROM db.accounts as act
  WHERE act.level = 'Level 4' 
    AND act.report = p_report;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

The above assumes that the column `account` is of type `text`. If it is not, then you need to adjust the data type in `RETURNS table(report_account text)` accordingly.

Then you can call it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM get_accounts('Report A');
```

---

Unrelated, but: a column alias that is the same as the column name doesn't really make sense. `"account" as account"` is exactly the same thing as `"account"`

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i still get only one result, don't know why...

Comment: @CaioCarvalho: if you defined and used the function as I have shown, the only explanation is that there is only one row matching the condition in that table

Comment: Don't know exactly what happened, but it seems that Postgres was not replacing the function. It worked when I `DROP FUNCTION get_account(text)` and then ran the code again. Thanks a lot.